# Editing entry in front-end

Tags: users, relations, form, entry

I am trying to edit an entry automatically when you press a button. Is there a way to do this?

A bit more detail: I have listed up a few entries, each with their own button. When I press the button on a specific entry, I want the currentUser to be added to the User Field of that entry.

Currently I have managed to get this semi-working with a form where the user can edit the entry through input fields etc., changing their value, then submiting (as outlined under [Entry Form](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form) in the docs). This is the prossess I want automated. When you press the button in the front-end the entry is edited with values set in the code and submitted.

Thanks!

Comment: Just trying to wrap my head around what you're going for. You've displaying a list of entries on the front-end. Each entry has a button. When a logged in user clicks one of the buttons, you want that user added to a Users field on that entry.

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, using hidden input fields :) Thank you for all the help :)

Edit: Ended up solving this by using tables and saving the username and ID in that. Used a plugin called Super Tables, which gives you a lot more control over the table.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/#{{ annonse.title }}{{ annonse.annonsePremie }}">
<input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="{{ annonse.sectionId }}">
<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ annonse.id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">

{# Start with the top-level Super Table field #}
<input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}]" value="">

{# Ensure any existing rows in your Super Table field are saved #}
{% for block in annonse[fieldHandle] %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ block.id }}][type]" value="{{ blocktype }}">
<input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ block.id }}][enabled]" value="1">
{% endfor %}

{# Add a new row of data - note the `new1` #}
<input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][new1][type]" value="{{ blocktype }}">
<input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][new1][enabled]" value="1">

{# Repeat for all your fields in your Super Table field #}
<input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][new1][fields][bruker]" value="{{ currentUser }}">
<input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][new1][fields][brukerId]" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

<button class="button submit" type="submit">
    <p>Submit</p>
</button>
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution? Might be helpful for someone in the future!

Comment: I have been trying for days to correctly save to my matrix field from a front end form. The code you provided in your own answer finally gave me the missing piece!! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to implement a feature to vote for entries. Have a look at these plugins, they make this really easy for you.

- https://www.doublesecretagency.com/plugins/upvote
- https://github.com/dukt/craft-like

If you want to implement something yourself, I would look into adding the button behavior using JavaScript, listen for click events and send the data over XMLHttpRequests to the entries/saveEntry controller.